# Bayesian inference - posterior in a simple model

Tags: regression, bayesian, inference

Suppose you are measuring $n$ quantities with error. Let $\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_n$ represent the true values and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ represent the measured values of those quantities.  Assume that the errors are centered normal. Let $\sigma_i^2\,, i=1, \ldots, n$ represent the **known** standard deviation of each measurement. So that the measurements are $$ X_i | \beta_i \sim N(\beta_i, \sigma_i^2)\,.$$

I can recover the above model by writing  $$ X_i = \beta_i + \varepsilon_i\,,$$ where $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma_{i}^2)$.

**Now I make the following extension to the model after which I get confused.**

Suppose that $\beta_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_b^2)$, with **known** parameters $\mu, \sigma_b^2$. I want to write down form of the posterior distribution $p(\beta_i | X)$.

---

On the one hand, if the relationship $X_i = \beta_i + \varepsilon_i $ is still in force, then
$$
\beta_i = X_i - \varepsilon_i
$$
so the posterior is 
$p(\beta_i | \{X_i\}) \sim N(X_i, \sigma_i^2)$ In particular it does not depend on $\sigma_b, \mu$.

On the other hand, if I just proceed by Bayesian theorem then 
$$
p(\beta_i | \{X_i\}) = \frac{p(\beta_i, \{X_i\})}{P(\{X_i\})} = \frac{p(\{X_i\}|\beta_i) p(\beta_i)}{P(\{X_i\})} \propto p(\{X_i\}|\beta_i) p(\beta_i) = f_1(\{X_i\}| \beta_i) f_2(\beta)\,,
$$

with $f_1(\{X_i\}| \beta_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i| \beta_i)$ where $ f(X_i; \beta_i)$ is density of $N(\beta_i, \sigma_i^2)$ and $f_2(\beta_i)$ is the density of $N(\mu, \sigma_b^2)$.

---

The results of those two approaches differ, what am I confusing here?

**Added late**: As one of the comments suggested my question is related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194784/deriving-the-ridge-regression-boldsymbol-beta-mid-mathbfy-distribution/194794#194794), but the  refereed question asks about the specific form of posterior distribution (why the posterior is normally distributed), this is different from what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the intention is that the $\epsilon$s are independent of the $\beta$s (like in a typical measurement noise model).

Then, $\epsilon_i$ and $X_i=\beta_i+\epsilon_i$ are not independent. The error in the first approach is assuming they are and proceeding as if $\epsilon_i \mid X_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i^2)$ would hold.

Comment: Thanks, so full model specification in the first case should be $ X_i = \beta_i + \varepsilon_i $ plus the fact that $\beta_i $ and $\varepsilon_i$ are independent, in that sense $X_i$ are not symmetric to $\beta_i$, since $X_i$ are not independent of $\varepsilon_i$.  $\varepsilon_i |X_i$ is degenerate random variable and  I have $\varepsilon_i |X_i = (X_i - \beta_i) $.

Comment: $\epsilon_i\mid X_i$ is not degenerate (as in constant) unless you treat $\beta_i$ as a constant.

Comment: Juho Kokkala,  thanks for pointing out. Under the model I have described it follows that $\varepsilon | X_i \sim N(X_i  - \mu, \sigma_b^2)$.