# Posterior distribution $\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y}$ for linear regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, posterior

In the linear regression model, we have
$$\mathbf{y} \mid \boldsymbol\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\theta, \boldsymbol\Sigma_{\boldsymbol\eta})$$
$$\boldsymbol\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\theta_0, \boldsymbol\Sigma_0)$$

I am interested in finding the distribution of $\boldsymbol\theta \mid\mathbf{y}$.

From my work after [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594859/completing-the-square-in-n-dimensions) as well as a more general result that I used, as well as a more [general result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/194794/46427) that I was given here in Stats SE, I obtain
$$\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0 \right)^{-1}(\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0\boldsymbol\theta_0+\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{\boldsymbol\eta}^{-1}\mathbf{y}),  \left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0 \right)^{-1}\right)\text{.}\tag{1}$$
However, Theodoridis states that on p. 88 of *Machine Learning* that 
$$\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y}]=\boldsymbol\theta_0 + \left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0 \right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{\boldsymbol\eta}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\theta_0)\tag{2}$$
(our variance matrices agree).

I don't see how $\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y}]$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ should agree. I attempted using the [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) and obtained
$$\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0 \right)^{-1}=\boldsymbol\Sigma_0-\boldsymbol\Sigma_0\mathbf{X}^{\prime}(\boldsymbol\Sigma_{\boldsymbol\eta}+\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\Sigma_0\mathbf{X}^{\prime})^{-1}\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\Sigma_0$$
and when doing the multiplication as in $(1)$, I obtain
$$\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0 \right)^{-1}(\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_0\boldsymbol\theta_0+\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{\boldsymbol\eta}^{-1}\mathbf{y})=\boldsymbol\theta_0+\boldsymbol\theta_0\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}_{\boldsymbol\eta}\mathbf{y}-\text{a mess...}$$
which doesn't look correct. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: In the expectation of (1) write $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} \boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ 
as $[\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} + \mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}^{-1}\mathbf{X}] \boldsymbol{\theta}_0 - \mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}^{-1}\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}_0 $.

Comment: @Yves Thank you very much! If you would like to put that as an answer, please do so, and I can award you points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expectation of (1) write $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} \boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ 
as $[\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} + 
\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}^{-1} \mathbf{X}] \, \boldsymbol{\theta}_0 - \mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}^{-1}\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}_0 $. By simply rearranging we get (2).